# spark convert Dataframe error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to convert a rdd to DataFrame, it gave me type mismatch error, but actually the type is defined in the case class. how to fix it ?

```
 var data = Array(Array("4/1/2014 1:01:00",40.7575,-73.9846,"B02512")) 
    var rdd = sc.makeRDD(data)    

    case class X(dt: java.sql.Timestamp, lat: Double, lon: Double, base: String)
    var newDF = rdd.map { case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => X(s0, s1, s2, s3) }.toDF()
```

Error:

```
    <console>:30: error: type mismatch;
     found   : Any
     required: java.sql.Timestamp
            var newDF = rdd.map { case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => X(s0, s1, s2, s3) }.toDF()

<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
     found   : Any
     required: Double
            var newDF = rdd.map { case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3) => X(s0, s1, s2, s3) }.toDF()
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is of type `Array[Array[Any]]` so the map operation fails to convert a `Any` to a `java.sql.Timestamp` or a `Double`.

Why not make `data` an `Array[X]` already, in order to have a strongly typed object?

Comment: how to make this change ? I am new to scala.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your array has many different datatypes in it. The first value is a string, then two numbers and another string. So when it cant match it with one data type, by default it takes it as "Any".

This can typically be forced to take up a specific datatype by saying something like,

var data: Array[String] = new Array("abc","123")

But this wouldnt work for you since you have values of different datatype in your array. Either pass them all as strings and then typecase them inside the class, or use something more sophisticated than an array which can only hold one datatype.